# Compiling QT5 app for OSX path-version issues

Tags: macos, compiler-errors, qt5

I am trying to compile rpcEMU [instructions here](http://www.marutan.net/rpcemu/linuxcompile.html)for OSX (Mojave, everything updated) Xcode 10.3 QT5.13.

I can compile fine under Fedora Linux and it all works. Given my level of experience, cross compiling from Linux to OSX looks intimidating.

The error I get is

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:           "Emulator::modifier_keys_reset_signal()", referenced from:
Emulator::Emulator() in rpc-qt5.o
MainWindow::application_state_changed(Qt::ApplicationState) in main_window.o
```

part of the issue is that it appears that my qmake is from my anaconda install whereas I should be using the 5.13 that is in my Xcode install.

```
qmake -v -config release
QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.6.2 in /Users/.../anaconda3/lib
```

So a start would be to fix my QT Path. 
How do I do that?

Any general advice or pointers on pursuing this would be gratefully received.

I have searched for relevant questions but again, a relevant question **with a relevant answer** would be useful.

Comment: Isn't it set with `QTTOOLDIR` and `QTLIBDIR`?

Comment: I don not really know how this works for OSX. Where is the $PATH set and where should a qt5 install have put qmake? (in MacOS)

Comment: It isn't macOS-specific; it works on all platforms AFAIK.  It's been a long time since I've used Qt so you might want to research it on places like the [Qt forums](https://forum.qt.io/topic/63773/setting-qt-environment-path/5) etc.